# How to return matrix (2D array) from function? (C)

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I created a function that generates a bingo board  and I want to return the bingo board.

as I didn't expect for , it doesn't work.

here is the function:

```
int** generateBoard() {
    int board[N][M], i, j , fillNum;
    Boolean exists = True;
    // initilize seed
    srand(time(NULL));
    // fill up..
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            exists = True;
            while(exists) {
                fillNum = rand()%MAX_RANGE + 1; // limit up to MAX_RANGE
                if(beenAdded(board, fillNum) == Exist) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    board[i][j] = fillNum;
                    exists = False;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

I have a compilcation error (the red subline) at "return board" line.

is there way to return a 2D array **without** using structs \ dynamic allocations?

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010.

Comment: use malloc for board 2D array allocation,

Comment: I can't , this is homework .. if I would able to , I would do that..

Comment: You better. Right now you're returning a local variable that is no longer valid on exiting function scope. Its undefined behavior. is in-out param acceptable ?

Comment: No, because we didn't learn pointers yet. (even though I did ..). anyway, do so in function didn't required. I just think it more clear..

Comment: then pass 2D array as argument of generate board,, signature would become,
`int generateBoard(int **board)`

Comment: Is this function only ever called once? Did you learn the `static` keyword yet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Someone has to own the memory of that board *somewhere*, and more importantly, that ownership must extend back to the caller of this function. Without dynamic allocation, your only other real alternative is to send it into the function as in in/out parameter.

```
void generateBoard(size_t N, size_t M, int board[N][M])
{
    int i, j , fillNum;
    Boolean exists = True;
    // initilize seed
    srand(time(NULL));
    // fill up..
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            exists = True;
            while(exists) {
                fillNum = rand()%MAX_RANGE + 1; // limit up to MAX_RANGE
                if(beenAdded(board, fillNum) == Exist) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    board[i][j] = fillNum;
                    exists = False;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and invoke like this from your caller:

```
int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    const size_t M = 10;
    int board[N][M];

    generateBoard(N,M,board);

    ...
}
```

I would also consider relocatting the `srand()` call to the startup code in `main()`. It should ideally never be in some potentially repeat-callable function, and should be guaranteed to only be executed **once** per process execution. (note: I honestly can't remember if it is once per *thread* execution, but at this point in your coding learning curve I'm guessing multi-threading is not on the radar yet).

Finally, your random-fill loop is needlessly repetitious. There are better alternatives generating what you're apparently trying to do: create a random permutation of an existing set of numbers. As written you could spin for some time trying to fill those last few slots, depending on how much larger `MAX_RANGE` is compared to `(N*M)`.

Answer (score 21):

You defined `board` as a local variable - its memory is dealoccated as the function goes out of scope.

You can declare the board global, or you can create it dynamically like so:

```
int **allocate_board(int Rows, int Cols)
{    
    // allocate Rows rows, each row is a pointer to int
    int **board = (int **)malloc(Rows * sizeof(int *)); 
    int row;

    // for each row allocate Cols ints
    for (row = 0; row < Rows; row++) {
        board[row] = (int *)malloc(Cols * sizeof(int));
    }

    return board;
}
```

You will need to dynamically free the board:

```
// you must supply the number of rows
void free_board(int **board, int Rows) 
{
    int row;

    // first free each row
    for (row = 0; row < Rows; row++) {
         free(board[row]);
    }

    // Eventually free the memory of the pointers to the rows
    free(board);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int **setMatrix(int *row1, int *cols1) //return matrix
{
    int row, cols;
    int **matrix;
    printf("enter row:\n");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("enter cols:\n");
    scanf("%d",&cols);
    
    
    matrix=(int **)calloc(cols ,sizeof(int*));
      for(int i=0;i<cols ;i++)
      {
          matrix[i]=(int *)calloc(row ,sizeof(int));
      }
    *row1=row;
    *cols1=cols;
    return matrix;

    


}


int main()
{
   int row ,cols;
   int **matrix;

   matrix=setMatrix(&row, &cols); //get the matrix back 
    
   return 0;
 }
```